# Couchdb - Block futon for readers users

Tags: security, couchdb, couchdb-futon

I want to know how block the acess to futon (_utils) in couchdb for readers, allowing the access only for admins.
I need to do this why if a reader user acess the futon he can see the name of all my databases and how many documents there are. My application should let a reader acess an document only if he have the id of them.

Comment: I've just been searching for the answer to just this question, thanks for asking!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if you block futon, people will be able to find the list of databases using the couchdb API. I think the right solution is to put a webserver in front of couchdb and expose only what you need.

Comment: I thought about it a I have other reasons to put a webserver in front (extra sercurity layer). Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 8):

Quoting CouchDB's homepage:

> You can even serve web apps ***directly*** out of CouchDB.

You can disable the futon interface by opening default.ini from Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\CouchDB\etc\couchdb and commenting out the following line by putting a semi-colon in front of it:

```
;_utils = {couch_httpd_misc_handlers, handle_utils_dir_req, "../share/couchdb/www"}
```

You can find this line under the [httpd_global_handlers] header. This will completely disable the _utils handler and effectively disable Futon. You can re-enable it by uncommenting this line.

If you are serving an app directly out of Couch there are other handlers you may want to disable as well like the _all_dbs handler. This and other handlers can be found under the [httpd_global_handlers] section or the [httpd_db_handlers] section.

Comment: I don't have a `Program Files`.

Comment: At the time I was running Couch on Windows. If you are using Linux it will be a different directory altogether.

Answer (score 2):

You can go with any webserver but if you want a javascript focused approach then use node.js.
http://nodejs.org/